# Why does gvim --remote change order of files?

Tags: gvim

When I open multiple files in `gvim` with no options, they are assigned to buffers in the order I specify on the command line:

```
gvim foo.cpp foo.h bar.cpp bar.h
```

Doing `:ls` then yields:

```
1 %a   "foo.cpp"                  line 1
2      "foo.h"                    line 0
3      "bar.cpp"                  line 0
4      "bar.h"                    line 0
```

However, when I am using `--servername` and `--remote` to have only one instance of `gvim`, the files are loaded in a different order:

```
gvim --servername gvim 

// Later ...

gvim --servername gvim --remote foo.cpp foo.h bar.cpp bar.h
```

Then `:ls` yields:

```
2 %a   "foo.cpp"                  line 1
3      "bar.cpp                   line 0
4      "foo.h"                    line 0
5      "bar.h"                    line 0
```

(Note that buffer 1 is not missing. It's a hidden empty buffer named `[No Name]` that was created by the first call to `gvim` with no file arguments)

It looks like maybe the `--remote` option causes the files to be grouped by extension. Is there a way to make `--remote` load the files into buffers in the same order specified on the command line?

BTW, this is with stock gvim 7.4, on CentOS 6.9, with no `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc`, and no plugins installed.

**Update**:

It looks like whatever `gvim` is doing here has to do with the fact that it recognizes the extensions `.cpp` and `.h` as special in some way. If I replace `.cpp` with `.cat` and `.h` with `.dog`, the files are loaded in the same order specified on the command line, as expected.

Comment: I am wondering what happened to buffer one? Can you reproduce this with an uptodate Vim?

Comment: Did you try this on a different server to confirm your assumption of extension grouping? Or are you trying to draw an inference from one server, however many times? Maybe the order is by file read completion. Maybe some sort of handshake?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Buffer 1 is a hidden buffer from when I did the first `gvim --servername gvim`, with no file args. It creates an empty buffer (1) which it subsequently marks hidden when some files are opened. Doing `:ls!` to also show hidden buffers shows buffer 1 as `[No Name]`.

Comment: @wbogacz I'm not making any assumptions. That's just what it *looks like* it's doing. Hence why I said maybe. And this isn't actually on a separate server. This is all on the local machine. I'm just using `--servername` to maintain a single instance of `gvim`.

Comment: @wbogacz Also, ordering by read completion can't be the explanation for this, because these are all non-existent (new) files.

Comment: It seems the order is (incorrectly?) influenced by the `suffixes` option if you use the `--remote` command line parameter. According to `:help 'suffixes'` this option should only have an effect on file names with wildcards. Maybe you can file a bug report at the Vim repository, if others come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @BLayer Sorry for the delayed response, and thanks for taking the time to find the answer.

Comment: @MikeHolt No worries. Glad I could provide the information you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `--remote` is the issue here. I can reproduce what you observed with a normal vim instance and the `args` command (e.g. `args a.c a.h b.h b.c` then `args` will show he two `.h` files at the end).

I went through the code a bit last night (disclaimer: it's been years since I used C with any regularity) and it looks like `expand_wildcards()` followed by `gen_expand_wildcards()` are called from `do_arglist()` for any `args <filelist>` command. That is, when setting/overwriting the `args` values (versus appending) and regardless of whether wildcards are present.

So we get to `gen_expand_wildcards()` which is summarized in the function comment which includes this:

```
If there are no wildcards: Add the file name if it exists or when EW_NOTFOUND is given.
```

Well, `EW_NOTFOUND` is passed in from `do_arglist()` so that accounts for this happening with files that have yet to be created.

Okay so `gen_expand_wildcards()` returns the original file list we specified to `expand_wildcards()`. That's where we find the culprit: the code under this comment is executed unconditionally:

```
Move the names where 'suffixes' match to the end.
```

As Jürgen Krämer correctly surmised in his comment the root cause is related to an apparently undocumented application of the value in `'suffixes'`.

Is it a bug? Probably only against the documentation as the code suggests the intent was always to do what is currently being done. The good news is you can work around the behavior if you'd like by modifying (temporarily) the value of `'suffixes'`...`set suffixes-=.h` for instance.